# libclang - parsing multiple source files - Python bindings

Tags: python, parsing, clang

Using Python bindings for `libclang`, how can I parse multiple files at once?

I have a compilation database, but from the Python bindings, the method `clang.cindex.Index.parse()` can only parse one file at a time (and gives you a translation unit corresponding to the parsed file).

Any efficient way to parse all the files (in the compilation database) in a single go?
Or, one has to get and work with a `TU` for each parsed file (individually)

Comment: That's the nature of C (or C++): every source file is a separate translation unit. If you just concatenate the files, it can change the semantics of the program.

Comment: Makes sense. I was hoping if there's a way to speed up the parsing by not having libclang reparse certain header files that were already parsed due to another source file.

Comment: you may be able to use precompiled headers to speed up header parsing. But you still have multiple translation units.